# C# data scraping from websites

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

HI I am pretty new in C# sphere. Been in php and JavaScript since the beginning of this year. I want to scrap posts and comments from a blog. The site is http://www.somewhereinblog.net

What I want to do is
1. I want to log in using a software
2. Then download the html
3. Then use regular expressions, xpath whatever comes handy to separate the contents of posts and comments

I been searching all over. Understood very little. Though I am quite sure I need to use 'htmlagilitypack'. I dont know how to add a library to c# console or form application. Can someone give me some help? I badly need this. And I am not too into C# just a week. So would be grateful if there is some detailed information. Waiting eagerly.

Thanks in advance brothers.

Comment: just google for some samples https://www.google.com/search?q=crawler+with+htmlagilitypack

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Using [Webclient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) you can login and download
2. Instead html-agility-pack I like [CsQuery](http://blog.outsharked.com/2012/06/ive-been-neglecting-csquery-c-jquery.html) because lets you use jQuery syntax inside a string in C# code, so you can download to a string the html, and search and do things in it like with jQuery and HTML page.

Comment: I love jquery. You made it super easy bro. Can you please leave me your email? I think I would need a little more help while developing the application.

Comment: @FlatLander Sure, but I think if you ask here you can get more feedback that only mine. leontiscar ----at---- gmail ---- dot ----- com